# How to find the expectation and variance of a right censored weibull distribution

Tags: r

I want to find the expectation and variance of a right censored weibull distribution.
Also, I what to plot its probability density function. Somehow I found `plot()` doesn't work.

These are the two parameters of the weibull distribution that I need. And I want a value that is larger that 1.5 times of its expectation, equal to 1.5 times expectation of the weibull distribution, as the right censored details:

```r
fitxtxo2$estimate
      shape       scale 
   1.625731 2353.861786
```